# how to remove the leading zeros in date format as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using jquery calendar from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094345/jquery-calendar-disabled-date-colour) it basically change the background color of the disabled dates in red

```
 <input id="iDate">

<script>
  var unavailableDates = ["09-10-2018", "14-09-2018", "15-10-2018"];

  function unavailable(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
          return [true, ""];
      } else {
          return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
      }
  }

  $(function() {
      $("#iDate").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'd-m-yy',
          beforeShowDay: unavailable
      });

  });
</script>
```

as you can see i have 3 disabled dates, the "09-10-2018" and "14-09-2018" does not disable in my calendar because of the leading zeros of day and month but when i try to remove the zeros of the day and month its working.

i also look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913580/jquery-trim-leading-zeros-from-date-of-format-01-02-2010) but i dont undestand

by the way the unavailaDates are coming from database so its not hardcoded thats why it generate leading zeros in day and month.

i appreciate whoever help me. 
im a beginner
sorry for bad english

Comment: What if you just set dateFormat to: `dd-mm-yy`?

Comment: @BryanH its display leading zero also to be exact here what it looks like "09-10-2018"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `date.getDate()` and `date.getMonth()` return integers, which cannot have leading zeros, therefore there will never be a match.

Simple fix, create a function:

```
function pad(num) {
  var s = "" + num;
  if ( num < 10 ) {
    s = "0" + num; 
  }
  return s;
}
```

Then do:

```
dmy = pad(date.getDate()) + "-" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
      "-" + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , your a savior for me haha i appreciate your response it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padStart` and compare both formats:

```js
var unavailableDates = ["01-10-2018", "2-10-2018", "13-10-2018"];

function unavailable(date) {
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    var dmy2 = ((date.getDate()+'').padStart(2,'0')) + "-" + (((date.getMonth() + 1)+'').padStart(2,'0')) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1 && $.inArray(dmy2, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker td.ui-state-disabled>span{background:#c30;}
.ui-datepicker td.ui-state-disabled{opacity:100;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="iDate">
```

Comment: It's good to know. You are welcome, and please upvote this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think @Bryanh maybe on to something.
But direct answer to your question is:

```
let d = '09-10-2018';
let newD = d.split('-').map(n=>{
    return parseInt(n)
}).join('-')
console.log(newD);
```